# Assign Strings At First Index Of NSArray To NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I am trying to find a particular url strings from a string named "newString". I am using the following code to detect the links and save them in an array called "matches". The particular strings i am interested in is located at matches[1] index of the array:

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:newString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
NSLog(@"MATCHES %@", matches[1]);
```

How can i assign the strings located at matches[1] to an NSString so i can use it further in my program?

Comment: What is the problem then ...? **NSLog(@"MATCHES %@", matches[1]);** If you are getting the log then, What **%@** indicate ..?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the problem with the line of code you told gives <NSLinkCheckingResult: 0xb6ecee0>{426, 107} { here is the link } as an output.

Comment: @KumarKl see the comment above

Answer (score 0):

`NSString *stringYouWant = [matches objectAtIndex:1];`

Or even

`NSString *stringYouWant = [[matches objectAtIndex:1] copy];`

Comment: of course i have tried that. If i log, it gives the output: <NSLinkCheckingResult: 0xb6ecee0>{426, 107} { here is the link }

Comment: I want only the link part not the <NSLinkCheckingResult and the memory location part in the start of it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was a bit premature :-) see iPatels answer. He is totally correct.

Comment: The solutions by iPatel is also not working. Check my comments below his answer

Answer (score 0):

**In your code**

```
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
    NSURL *url = [match URL];
    NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
    break;
  }
}
```

Other way is use `NSRegularExpression`.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:[regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];
NSLog(@"%@", match);
```

Comment: the first code you provided doesn't return the correct url. It starts giving me the links at index 0 while i want the links at index 1. If i use matches[1] instead of matches in the line (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) then it crashes.

Comment: and how can i use the NSRegularExpression code? I have tried the code you provided and it returns "vertical-align:top" in the log. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Does one of these solutions work for you?
Did you try another match (0, 2, 3, ...)?
You could also try a range at another index...

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:newString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
NSURL *urlYouWant = [[matches objectAtIndex:1] URL];
NSString *stringYouWant = [newString subStringWithRange:[[matches objectAtIndex:1] rangeAtIndex:1]];
```